# Website to publish posts/stories but with visibility controls

Tags: blog

Looking for a free, hosted, webapp  like "Blogger", but there must be a way to (at a minimum) toggle the visibility of posts after publishing them.

Btw, visibility changes should not modify the <Date Published> of posts.

---

Another requirement is that I wish not to have to use anything that is created by "*more money than any brains*", ie Medium / Evan Williams and Quora / D'Angelo.

Comment: While website recommendations are off-topic here (see: [Can I ask for recommended websites?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/185)), you might wish to take a look at [Write Freely](https://writefreely.org/). It is part of the [Fediverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fediverse), so you can host your own instance (which makes it on-topic here) or join an [existing instance](https://the-federation.info/platform/40). I haven't tried it myself, so I cannot tell if it meets your requirements.

Comment: @Izzy,  edited.͏

Comment: You might have liked Nabble (their blogs) while it was open to new users. Of course, the Nabble software is out there for download, but I don't know how to set it up. You could set up a private place where you move your private posts. There wasn't a simple toggle per post.

Comment: If you want to be unconventional, you can always just manually encrypt and enarmor your private blog posts, and decrypt them when you want to make them public. :)

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx, [yet not undiscoverable](https://pastebin.com/raw/nq6Y57xf).